# How to zip only the files inside the folder and not the sub folders?

Tags: python, windows, zip

I have a folder structure as:

```
/sample/debug/
    --debug.exe
    --sample.exe
    --sample.pdb
    --debug.pdb
    --sample.dll
    --debug.dll
    /config
        --sample.txt
        --new.txt
    /general
        --general.txt
        --code.txt
```

So, what I want is only to zip the files inside debug and not the subfolders like /config and /general. I tried as follows:

```
import zipfile
import os

def append( dir_name ):
    ret_val = []
    fileList = []
    for file in os.listdir(dir_name):
        try:
            dirfile = os.path.join(dir_name, file)
        except Exception:
            err = sys.exc_info()
            print ("Error!", err)
        fileList.append(dirfile)
        ret_val = fileList
    return ret_val

def zip( fileList, archive, root ):
    ret_val = 0
    try:
        zip_folder_contents = zipfile.ZipFile(archive, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    except Exception:
        err = sys.exc_info()
        print ("Error!",err)
        exit( 1 )
    for filename in fileList:
        zip_folder_contents.write(filename,
                filename[len(root):].lstrip(os.path.sep).lstrip(os.path.altsep))
    zip_folder_contents.close()
    return ret_val

make(append_files_in_zipfolder("D:/sample/debug"), "debug.zip",
                               "D:/sample/debug")
```

Now when I execute above I get error as permission denied "D:/sample/debug\\config". Hence, I am not able to remove this error so I thought to only include the files inside the zip folder and exclude the subfolders. So, is there anyway how to do that or some way I can remove this permission related error I am getting. Please suggest.

Comment: What is `make()`? Where is definition of function `append_files_in_zipfolder()`?

Comment: Look through the [Files and Directories](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#files-and-directories) section of the ```os``` module, pick some methods that will help you weed out the directories, formulate some logic to weed out directories, put it all together and zip the files.  ```os.walk``` is probably overkill but it might make it simple.  there are a few others that will make it easy/possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can grab all files from a folder without going into the subfolders using:

```
import os
def getfilesfrom(directory):
    return filter(lambda x:
                  not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, x)),
                  os.listdir(directory))

# or alternatively, using generators (as suggested in the comments):
def getfilesfrom(directory):
    for x in os.listdir(directory):
        if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, x)):
            yield x  # or yield os.path.join(directory, x) for full path.
```

You can then simply run (as described in the [documentation](https://pymotw.com/2/zipfile/)):

```
import datetime
import zipfile

def print_info(archive_name):
""" Print information from zip archive"""
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(archive_name)
for info in zf.infolist():
    print info.filename
    print '\tComment:\t', info.comment
    print '\tModified:\t', datetime.datetime(*info.date_time)
    print '\tSystem:\t\t', info.create_system, '(0 = Windows, 3 = Unix)'
    print '\tZIP version:\t', info.create_version
    print '\tCompressed:\t', info.compress_size, 'bytes'
    print '\tUncompressed:\t', info.file_size, 'bytes'
    print

print 'creating archive'
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('debug.zip', mode='a', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
inputdir = '/sample/debug/'
filestozip = getfilesfrom(inputdir)
for afile in filestozip:
    print('adding ' + afile + ' to zipfile debug.zip')
    zf.write(os.path.join(inputdir, afile), afile)

print 'closing'
zf.close()

print
print_info('debug.zip')
```

Comment: i did as suggested but got error as "the system cannot find file specified " debug.exe. in line 'zf.write(afile).

Comment: what if you try with `zf.write(os.path.join(inputdir, afile))`, does it fix the problem? Just edited the code. I also changed the mode from `'w'` to `'a'`, otherwise you'll overwrite the files as you loop through them.

Comment: i did that also but now i am getting debug.zip folder which has zipped all the folders from the root directory i.e debug.zip contains folders starting from '/sample/' root directory but i don't  want complete directory to get zipped. i only want files inside the zipped folder. what shall i do

Comment: `zf.write(os.path.join(inputdir, afile), afile)`

Comment: if you made `getfilesfrom` a generator it would take the same amount of lines but easier to read: `for x in os.listdir(directory): if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, x): yield x` it would also make it easier to adapt to make it generate `os.path.join(directory, x)` instead of the filenames alone.

Answer (score 0):

The following makes use of the new ZipFile context manager available:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

def zip_folder(zip_name, folder):
    with ZipFile(zip_name, 'w') as myzip:
        for entry in os.listdir(folder):
            if os.path.isfile(entry):
                myzip.write(os.path.join(folder, entry), arcname=entry)

zip_folder(r'D:\output.zip', r'D:\sample\debug')
```